Meromorphic continuation of Euler product
Short version: What can be said about the meromorphic continuation of the Euler product $$\prod _{p}\left (1+\frac {p^{-s}}{p-2}\right )?$$
Longer version: I realise I have some misconceptions about meromorphically continuing Euler products, even with products easier than the one above. So let me try to present my understanding and hopefully people can tell me what I'm understanding incorrectly:
Write $Y=p^{-s}$. The function $$\prod _p(1+Y)\hspace {10mm}(1)$$ obviously has meromorphic continuation to the whole of $\mathbb C$ since it's $\zeta (s)/\zeta (2s)$. I then thought that a function like $$\prod _p(1+Y+Y/p^{100})\hspace {10mm}(2)$$ also has meromorphic continuation to say $\sigma \approx -99$ since obviously the $Y/p^{100}$ is tiny for $\sigma >-99$. But I can't actually write anything more down than $$\prod _p(1+Y+Y/p^{100})=\prod _p(1+Y)\prod _p\left (1+\frac {Y}{p^{100}(1+Y)}\right )=\frac {\zeta (s)}{\zeta (2s)}\mathcal F(s)$$ with $\mathcal F(s)$ holomorphic for nothing better than $\sigma >0$. So now I'm not even sure if it does have continuation past $0$. If so, how do I extend it?
We have $$(1+Y+Y/p^{100})(1-Y)=1-Y^2+Y/p^{100}-Y^2/p^{100}$$
$$(1+Y+Y/p^{100})(1-Y)(1+Y^2)=1+Y^4+Y/p^{100}-Y^2/p^{100}+Y^3/p^{100}+Y^4/p^{100}$$ but continuing this process also only gives me continuation up to zero (and perhaps even a cluster of zeros and therefore $\sigma =0$ is a natural boundary?) Finally, is this product even relevant to the one in my original question?
Apologies if I'm missing something obvious. I guess there's a big difference between (1) and (2).

The "Estermann phenomenon" might be interesting in this regard... (later enormously extended by Kurokawa). That is, for example, $\sum_n d(n)^k/n^s$, for $d(n)$ the number of divisors of $n$, has a meromorphic continuation for $k=0,1,2$, but not for $k=3$.

ye, i was aware of that phenomenon and example but thought that it was relevant that the polynomial was just in $p^{-s}$, not in $p^{-s},p$ as in my examples. is the extension by kurokawa relevant then? i couldn't see that it is, but i think this is maybe because i don't really know much about general l-functions/euler products ("artin L-functions" is mentioned often in his results?)

unfortunately, I've not thought much about this, so cannot say anything useful. But, still, I am interested in case anyone knows how such a thing works out. :)

ah, well, never mind:) (do come back to this question if you have any flashes of inspiration at some point:D )

A comment that got too long. First I assume one wants $p \ge 3$ in the first product.
Then I find it highly likely that the first product has the $\Re s =-1$ as natural boundary while the second has $\Re s =0$ as such and probably one can cobble up a proof with care.
Note that factoring $\Pi_{p \ge 3}(1+p^{-s-1})$ gives us that $$\prod _{p \ge 3}\left (1+\frac {p^{-s}}{p-2}\right )=\frac {\zeta (s+1)}{(1+2^{-s-1})\zeta (2s+2)}\mathcal G(s), \Re s >0$$ and we have $$\mathcal G(s)=\Pi_{p \ge 3}(1+\frac{2}{(p-2)(p^{-s-1}+1)p^{s+1}})$$ so $\mathcal G$ is absolutely convergent for $\Re s >-1$
But $\mathcal G$ contains one very large factor for a set of $s$ that accumulates to a dense subset of $\Re s >-1$, namely the roots of $p^{-s-1}+1=0$ so $-1+(2k+1)\pi i/ \log p$ so letting $s_{p,k}=-1+\epsilon+(2k+1)\pi i/ \log p$ the corresponding $p$ factor goes to infinity as $\epsilon \to 0$. Hence in particular if $\mathcal G$ would have a meromorphic extension at $\Re s =-1$, the poles cannot accumulate, so generally speaking the corresponding large term would need to be cancelled by small terms and of course while that is definitely possible, I find it kind of unlikely.
A similar reasoning should work for the second function and $\Re s >0$ as now $p^s+1=0$ at a dense set there (when considering all $p$ of course).
Note that the smallness of a perturbation $h$ doesn't tell us anything about the meromorphic continuation of $f(s)+h(s)$ when we know that $f$ is meromorphically continuable but doesn't converge absolutely in its sense beyond a line or a circle (eg when $f$ is a Dirichlet series, a power series, an Euler product etc) as is easily seen by perturbing $z$ with a very small function on the unit disc that is holomorphic inside and for example has all its derivatives converging absolutely on the unit circle too (so if $h(z)=\sum h_nz^n, n^kh_n \to 0, n \to \infty$ for all $k$) but has the unit circle as a natural boundary - then putting $z=2^s$ give a Dirichlet series example and some tinkering should give an Euler product example

i see. thank you!
